# <p>field<p> with p { letter-spacing: 6px;} not spaced correctly

Tags: html, css

Apologies for including code within the title but it was the easiest way of explaining my small problem.

With the following html:

```
<p>the field of</p>
```

And the accompanying CSS:

```
p {letter-spacing: 6px;}
```

The 'f','i' and 'e' don't space correctly.

I wondered why this happens and also how to fix it.

Here is a small accompanying image of the problem so you can see it:

[image]

Comment: Have you checked different browsers?

Comment: It seems to work perfectly in Google Chrome...

Comment: then its just a font/browser issue. css is just fine.

Comment: So I would assume their is no real fix...

Comment: Well use a better font, that's the only real fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect this might be a font and/or OS bug. Where are you seeing this?

In general, this works as expected. (See [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bvaughn/5ugy4zho/))

I am using the same code as you are:

```
<p>the field of</p>
```

with

```
p {letter-spacing: 6px;}
```

and I am seeing the desired result

Comment: The font I'm using is PT Sans. I'm launching it locally in Safari. What do you mean by OS bug...

Comment: @MichaelRoberts try the same with other font and on other browser as well, check if the same issue repeats.

Comment: It works fine with other fonts in both Safari and Chrome, and it works within Chrome with PT Sans.

Comment: Then its definitely a problem with your PT Sans font.

Comment: I updated my Jsbin example to use Google's PT+Sans font and it renders fine for me on Ubuntu+Chrome. (I can't check with Safari or I would.)

Comment: I was wondering if it was an error similar to copying double ffs from pdf. Not sure if anyone has had that.

Answer (score 0):

It's depend on the font and the also how the browser render it.

Try to use web fonts and then check it in the Firefox, Chrome etc.